How do I find the radius of a circle that's equivalent to a non-circular curve?
I have been studying uniform circular motion, and all the equations are set out in terms of the radius of the circle along which a body is moving. e.g. $$F_c=\frac{mv^2}{r}$$
However, not all curves are circular. Sometimes I find problems like this:
Find $F_c$ if a car of mass $x$ kg travels over a circular hill of radius $y$ m at $1\text{ m s}^{-1}$.

To be perfectly clear, this is not the question I'm asking for help with. I can solve questions like these if I know what the radius is.
While solving one of these, however, I realised that we can't know the actual radius of a hill in real life. We can calculate the slope by doing measurements but there's no actual way to find the radius. Yet, it seems we need the radius to do physics on the curve.
So if we knew the function of a non-circular curve, how could we find the radius of the equivalent circle at a point that we could plug into the circular motion formulas?
My first instinct was to take the derivative of the curve. I figured that the slope of the curve at a point must somehow be related to the radius of the circle, but then I realised that the derivative of a circle varies depending on which point you evaluate it at. It seems like there's no way to equate the derivative of a function with the circle. I'd appreciate some pointers on where to go from here. If I had to guess, it'd involve taking the second derivative somehow but I'm not sure what I'd do with that.
Also, what does it even mean for a curve to be equivalent to a circle in the first place? Aren't there infinite circles that you can place next to a curve, such as in the first diagram?

You are right, not all curves are circles.
However, for any curve and at any point there is a "kissing circle" that fits the curve at that point.  And so we can model the motion at a point as motion around a circle.
If you want to dive deeper, here is an article on finding the radius of that circle for a general curve.
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RadiusofCurvature.html

Some of the links in that article may be a bit over my head but I do appreciate the quick reply. And I also now know the name of what I'm talking about (radius of curvature)

the $r$ in the centripetal force formula will be replaced by $\rho$ which is the radius of curvature of the curve. You can calculate $\rho$ given the parametric equation of the curve by means of the frenet-serret formulas.

If you want to impress someone, call it an "osculating circle."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_circle#:~:text=An%20osculating%20circle%20is%20a,the%20curve%20at%20that%20point.


While solving one of these, however, I realised that we can't know the actual radius of a hill in real life. We can calculate the slope by doing measurements but there's no actual way to find the radius.

I think this is worth diving into.

The slope is the first derivative of elevation.
The radius of curvature is a function of the first and second derivatives of elevation.

Since derivatives are mathematical ideals, there's a sense in which neither the slope nor the radius can be calculated from real-world measurements that you can actually perform.
On the other hand, if you're willing to approximate the slope using finite measurements, then it is also possible to approximate the radius using finite measurements. For example, you can approximate the slope using two nearby elevations, and you can also approximate the radius using three nearby elevations.

Yes, of course we don't have a way to find the exact radius of curvature in real life. However, my question doesn't stem from a need to solve a real-life problem, but rather an interest in whether we could find the radius of curvature in a theoretical case where the curve is a perfect mathematical function.

I would likely accept this answer if you could elaborate on how we can find the radius of curvature in the way you said in the second bullet point.

Oh, there are formulas in the linked articles in the other answer. Beware, they're not pretty.

WIll take a look at them but I'm not sure I can accept that answer either given that the answer's in links. It's also over my head.

Hmm, it may be worthwhile asking a separate follow-up question, then. For example, let's say you want to know more about equation (5) in the MathWorld article. You could ask how to use it, or how to derive it, or some other avenue of question.

(This community wiki answer is for collecting answers that were posted as comments, to ensure that they are indexed by search and recognized as answering the question.)

You are right, not all curves are circles. However, for any curve and at any point there is a "kissing circle" that fits the curve at that point. And so we can model the motion at a point as motion around a circle. If you want to dive deeper, here is an article on finding the radius of that circle for a general curve. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RadiusofCurvature.html –
user317176


the r
in the centripetal force formula will be replaced by ρ
which is the radius of curvature of the curve. You can calculate ρ
given the parametric equation of the curve by means of the frenet-serret formulas. –
tensorman666


If you want to impress someone, call it an "osculating circle." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_circle#:~:text=An%20osculating%20circle%20is%20a,the%20curve%20at%20that%20point –
David G. Stork

